# Recode if string (with punctuation) contains certain text

Tags: r, string, recode

How can I search through a character vector and, if the string at a given index contains a pattern, replace that index's value?

I tried this:

```
List <- c(1:8)
  Types<-as.character(c(
    "ABC, the (stuff).\n\n\n fun", "meaningful", "relevant", "rewarding", 
    "unpleasant", "enjoyable", "engaging", "disinteresting"))
  for (i in List) {
    if (grepl(Types[i], "fun", fixed = TRUE))
    {Types[i]="1"
    } else if (grepl(Types[i], "meaningful", fixed = TRUE))
    {Types[i]="2"}}
```

The code works for "meaningful", but doesn't when there's punctuation or other things in the string, as with "fun".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `grepl` is the pattern, not the string.

This would be a literal fix of your code:

```r
for (i in seq_along(Types)) {
  if (grepl("fun", Types[i], fixed = TRUE)) {
    Types[i] = "1"
  } else if (grepl("meaningful", Types[i], fixed = TRUE)) {
    Types[i] = "2"
  }
}
Types
# [1] "1"              "2"              "relevant"       "rewarding"      "unpleasant"    
# [6] "enjoyable"      "engaging"       "disinteresting"
```

BTW, the use of `List` works, but it's a little extra: when you have separate variables like that, it is possible that one might go out of sync with the other. For instance, if you update `Types` and forget to update `List`, then it will break (or fail). For this, I used `seq_along(Types)` instead.

BTW: here's a slightly different version that leaves `Types` untouched and returns a new vector, and is introducing you to the power of vectorization:

```r
Types[grepl("fun", Types, fixed = TRUE)] <- "1"
Types[grepl("meaningful", Types, fixed = TRUE)] <- "2"
Types
# [1] "1"              "2"              "relevant"       "rewarding"      "unpleasant"    
# [6] "enjoyable"      "engaging"       "disinteresting"
```

---

The next level (perhaps over-complicating?) would be to store the patterns and recoding replacements in a frame (always a 1-to-1, you'll never accidentally update one without the other, can be stored in CSV if needed) and `Reduce` on it:

```r
ptns <- data.frame(ptn = c("fun", "meaningful"), repl = c("1", "2"))
Reduce(function(txt, i) {
  txt[grepl(ptns$ptn[i], txt, fixed = TRUE)] <- ptns$repl[i]
  txt
}, seq_len(nrow(ptns)), init = Types)
# [1] "1"              "2"              "relevant"       "rewarding"      "unpleasant"    
# [6] "enjoyable"      "engaging"       "disinteresting"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was staring at my code for too long 0_o

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str_replace_all`:

```
library(stringr)
pat <- c(fun = '1', meaningful = '2')
str_replace_all(Types, setNames(pat, sprintf('(?s).*%s.*', names(pat))))

[1] "1"              "2"              "relevant"      
[4] "rewarding"      "unpleasant"     "enjoyable"     
[7] "engaging"       "disinteresting"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)` from `string` package.

Comment: OP is trying to replace the entire string based on a pattern within the string, not just the match. You could replace `grepl` with `str_detect`, but `str_replace` is not a solution to this problem, at least not without some modification.

Comment: Touché! Thank's a lot for the clarification, Gregor!

Comment: @GregorThomas check the answer i posted